# How do I get this while loop and json response to work?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

The first time the script is run with input `userid` and if the user is online, it runs fine until the `print(f'{username}, {userid}' + ' is still online...')` gets stuck. 
The program never continues to the `else:` when the user go offline and  `while userid == str(ps['user_id']):` is no longer `True`.

It's like the `str(ps['user_id']):` never updates in the script when called.

```py
userid = input('Input userID: ')
response = requests.post('website.com/api', headers=headers, data=data)
json_data = json.dumps(response.json(), indent=2)
data = json.loads(json_data)

while True: # Main loop to run if a user is online
    for ps in data['result']['page']['list']:
        if userid == str(ps['user_id']): # If a user is online print details
            username = ps['nick_name']
            print('Username: ' + ps['nick_name'])
            print('UserID: ' + str(ps['user_id']))           
            while userid == str(ps['user_id']): # Look if the user is still online (is in the json response)
                print(f'{username}, {userid}' + ' is still online...')
                time.sleep(3)
        else: # If user go offline(is not in the json response), break and restart main loop(first while loop).
            break

        print('Waiting for ' + f'{userid}' + ' to get online...') # Message until user go online again (is found in the json response).
        time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: Where in that inner loop do you think ps or userid would change?

Comment: Is this a multithreaded program?  If it's not, then the data cannot possbly change inside the loops.  You need to update the data periodically if you want one of the conditional statments (the while or the if statements( to change from true to false.

Comment: It is not a multithreaded program. So I guess what I need is help to, how to have it update the data periodically?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I thought it would change when "calling" while userid == str(ps['user_id']) that's where I need it to "register" any changes in the in the dynamic json response. So have it look if the userid is still in the json response and if not the go to the "else:"  and break out and return to main loop ig

Comment: What makes you think that's dynamic? You only ever made one request.

Comment: @jonrsharpe It is an api for a live broadcasting service. So a user can go online(broadcasting) or go offline(not broadcasting) and there are many users. So I guess that is dynamic unless I use that term in the wrong way.

Comment: The data might be different *if you make another request* but your local dictionary isn't somehow magically subscribed to the server.

Comment: That's why I also tried with  if userid != str(ps['user_id']): but that will always be True i think since it iterate through userid's that is not equal to the input userid. Therefore that approach doesn't work either. I've tried so many things and now I am losing my mind heheh

Comment: @jonrsharpe ok, that's why i've tried to "request" the data again with another 'for' loop in the inner while loop too. But it doesn't change a thing :(

Comment: It's unclear why you think anything other than the first requests.post will request more data, but... it won't. Also there's absolutely no need to keep dumps- and loads-ing the JSON

Comment: @jonrsharpe I don't think anything, or actually I think many things. But I need help on this, why I ask this question. I don't seek a question to my question :) I've updated my post with another approach out of many I tried to have it "update".

Comment: @jonrsharpe I don't know what you mean by keep dumps- and loads-ing the json :/ Does that have anything to do with my problem or is it just a side comment? I'm here to learn so please explain that to me too, if you feel like it.

Comment: @jonrsharpe The forum says that this is turning into a discussion. Can you please make an answer where we can continue or can we continue in a chat? I really want your help if you are willing to provide it.

Comment: And this isn't a forum, and no I don't want to chat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not updating data anywhere inside of your loop so its using the same stale data for every iteration. You can just add your three lines to generate data into your loop before the time.sleep(5). This will give you updated data and should resolve your issue.

```
userid = input('Input userID: ')
response = requests.post('website.com/api', headers=headers, data=data)
json_data = json.dumps(response.json(), indent=2)
data = json.loads(json_data)
userList = data['result']['page']['list']
isOnline = 0

while True: # Main loop to run if a user is online
    hasLoggedIn = 0
    for user in userList:

        if str(user['user_id']) == userid and isOnline == 0: # If a user is online print details
            username = user['nick_name']
            print('Username: ' + user['nick_name'])
            print('UserID: ' + str(user['user_id']))
            print(f'{username}, {userid}' + ' is now online...')
            isOnline = 1
            hasLoggedIn = 1
            time.sleep(3)

        elif str(user['user_id']) == userid and isOnline == 1:       
            print(f'{username}, {userid}' + ' is still online...')
            hasLoggedIn = 1
            time.sleep(3)

    if hasLoggedIn == 0:    
        print('Waiting for ' + f'{userid}' + ' to get online...') # Message until user go online again (is found in the json response).
        isOnline = 0
        time.sleep(5)

    response = requests.post('website.com/api', headers=headers, data=data)
    json_data = json.dumps(response.json(), indent=2)
    data = json.loads(json_data)
    userList = data['result']['page']['list']
```

Comment: Ah I see and makes sense. But what 3 lines tho? I've tried tho to add: 

for ps in data['result']['page']['list']:
        if userid == str(ps['user_id']):  

in every loop with no change.

Comment: Most appreiciated if you can hand me the solution so I can read it an learn from it. Else I am just on to guessing. And I've already done 23 days of trial and error and split the two while loops into each their definitions with a while True and stuff.. I am at a point where the logic I am trying to find is failing me bigtime and I am the one stalling and being stuck. I've read about while loops, if loops, continue, break and many posts on here and tried so many different approaches. I just can't find the right solution. :(

Comment: You say before the time.sleep(5). But what about the inner while loop with time.sleep(3) and if not then "else:" ??

Comment: @aquatic7 Let me know if these changes are sufficient.

Comment: I have changed the ps['nickname'] and str(ps['user_id'] to user['nickname'] and str(user['user_id']) but get error when the user is online: "username = userList['nick_name']
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
" and when a user is not online in the last line: "userList = data['result']['page']['list']
KeyError: 'page'"

Comment: I have corrected the errors with username. As for the KeyError:page you will need to write some logic to determine if that that exists before trying to set userList. I was assuming that data['result']['page']['list'] would always exist even if empty

Comment: Thank you a lot! The logic about how to use isOnline= and hasLoggedIn= has been very helpful and educating! Now the only problem is the KeyError:page. The data['result']['page']['list'] does always exist even if empty. And the first time in the top of the script it's working fine, but it's the last time, on the last line it throws the error for some reason. Why is it ok the first time in the top of the script but not the second time at the bottom of the script?

Comment: Aaahhh I figured it out. It's because I ofc also needed the headers= and data= for the request inside the loop. All good now. Thank you A LOT!!

Comment: How can I pass the variable username from the inner loop to the outer if hasLoggedIn == 0: loop so I can have it say: 'Waiting for ' + f'{username}, f'{userid}' + ' to get online...'